# How to get number of specific rows from a different table in a subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I know it's possible, but I'm not experienced enough to know how to do subqueries.
Here's the situation:

```
Table 1:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               v_id |             v_name |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |            v_name1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| etc...

Table 2:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               a_id |             a_name |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |            a_name1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| etc...

Table 3:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               v_id |               a_id |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  2 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  3 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  2 |                  3 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  2 |                  1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I believe this is a quite common situation.
So, I have unique entries in `Table 1` and `Table 2`.
I want to `SELECT` all rows from `Table 1` and get (as the last cell in each row) the number of rows with the corresponding value in `Table 3`.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT t1.* , COUNT(SELECT t3.* FROM  `table_3` t3 WHERE t3.v_id = t1.v_id) as entries
FROM  `table 1` t1;
```

I'm sure I'm gonna be told off by experts here that it's all wrong, but frankly, that's what I'm looking for (and some helpful solution as well!). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT t1.*,
          COALESCE(x.num_rows, 0) AS entries
     FROM `table 1` t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.v_id,
                  COUNT(*) 'num_rows'
             FROM `table_3` t3
         GROUP BY t3.v_id) x ON x.v_id = t1.v_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.* , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `table_3` t3 WHERE t3.v_id = t1.v_id) as t3Count as entries 
FROM  `table 1` t1;
```

Comment: the subquery will execute for each row in the outer select, which for large resultsets will affect performance.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the plans used in almost every database system these days, you'll see that the correlated subquery will be executed as a join. Doing it this way makes it clearer that working out the value will not add or subtract from the number of rows returned by t1.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T1.v_id, COALESCE(COUNT(T3.v_id), 0)
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS T3
ON T1.v_id = T3.v_id
GROUP BY T1.v_id
```