# Database to return multi-dimensional result

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, multidimensional-array

This is a follow-up question to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143116/how-to-get-number-of-specific-rows-from-a-different-table-in-a-subquery).
Situation:

```
Table 1:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               v_id |             v_name |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |            v_name1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| etc...

Table 2:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               a_id |             a_name |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |            a_name1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| etc...

Table 3:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               v_id |               a_id |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  1 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  2 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |                  3 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to get a join of the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.a_name
FROM `table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_3` t3 ON t3.v_id = t1.v_id
LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t2.a_id = t3.a_id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

The result of this query will be 3 rows for the given tables, each row with the same values from `Table 1`, just a different `a_name` from `Table 3`.
Now, is it possible for me to make `a_name` an array (of 3 cells in this case)? I think that this is not possible. If it's not, how would I have to build the query so that it would return just one row, with the `a_name` results joined with a given 'glue' string?

---

**EDIT**
If I were to get a result in PHP, I would expect something like:

```
$result = array(
    'v_id'    => 1,
    'a_name'  => array('a_name1', 'a_name2', 'a_name3')
);
```

or

```
$result = array(
    'v_id'    => 1,
    'a_name'  =>'a_name1, a_name2, a_name3'), # assuming I used ', ' as the glue string
);
```

Comment: There aren't any array data types on SQL - please post an example of what your expected output should look like.  Sounds like GROUP_CONCAT...

Comment: I suggest that you *don't* implement this. Your original query is fine and is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I'm aware of potential pitfalls. I was just wondering on ways do decrease the number of connections from an application to database and get more details results directly from it.

Comment: OK... never mind - you know more about your problem than I do, so I can't know what's best for you. Good luck with this approach and watch out for commas in the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

In your query it would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.a_name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM `table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_3` t3 ON t3.v_id = t1.v_id
LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t2.a_id = t3.a_id
WHERE t1.id = 1
GROUP BY [list of t1 columns here] 
-- update thanks to OMG Ponies.
```

Comment: thank you. that does the trick good enough for me! appreciated!

Comment: one observation though. this solution works just fine for one row only. if we get rid of `WHERE` clause it will not produce valid results.

Comment: @Michal M: It's missing a `GROUP BY` clause.  MySQL, in it's infinite wisdom, allows for omitting columns from the `GROUP BY` and still working - no other db I'm aware of allows this, and causes pain (there's lots of "why does this work on MySQL but not DB XYZ..." on SO).  You need to list every column that is not wrapped in an aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT in this case) in the `GROUP BY`.  Here's the MySQL page about missing columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @Michal and @OMG Ponies: Updated.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
    SELECT t1.*, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.a_name SEPARATOR ',')
     FROM `table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_3` t3 ON t3.v_id = t1.v_id
LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t2.a_id = t3.a_id
   WHERE t1.id = 1
 GROUP BY [list of t1 columns here]
```

`Sean Viera`'s answer works as you pointed out because of the `WHERE` clause, and because [MySQL allows for columns to be omitted from the `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  It's not a good habit - only MySQL allows this, and such queries will not port to other databases (there's lots of examples on SO).

I added the distinct in the `GROUP_CONCAT` - didn't think you want duplicates if any exist.